# SQL get a last updated DATETIME field from EXACTLY 3 weeks ago

Tags: datetime, mariadb

This is the same query I used in the past for a DATE field, however for a DATETIME field it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    user_log
WHERE 
    log_updated = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 21 DAY);
```

I want a date from EXACTLY 21 days ago, but it can be of any time during that day. I do not want 21 days and over (or 21 days and under).

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using? Please don't tag multiple DBMS.

Comment: No worries Hana, the generic sql tag will be removed later to prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    user_log
WHERE 
    DATE(log_updated) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 21 DAY);
```

But then this is not an efficient ([sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/2469308)) solution, as using a function on the Column will impede the usage of indexing (if defined).

So, a **better** approach would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    user_log
WHERE 
    log_updated >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND 
    log_updated < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

**Notice** that I have used a day after the required date for maximum bound checking (not inclusive). It is obtained by `INTERVAL -20 DAY`

Comment: @Hana Please set this answer as accepted answer if it solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since `DATE(NOW())` is the same as `CURDATE()`, you may as well use

```
WHERE log_updated >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY
  AND log_updated  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

This may use an index on `log_updated`.

In contrast, `DATE(log_updated) ...` *cannot* use an index on `log_updated`.